# How to use carriage return (\r) with newline (\n) in python

Tags: python

I am trying to create a message that changes over time in Python. I know I will have to use a carriage return to write over the message. I want to print the following message:

```
It has been (n) minutes since you ran this

Time started: (date when program started)

Time: (date now)
```

But when I try to print it, I get this:

```
It has been 1 minute(s) since the past iteration. Since then, some pretty amazing stuff happened, like:
TIME STARTED: Tue Oct 27 2020, 11:14:41 PM
It has been 2 minute(s) since the past iteration. Since then, some pretty amazing stuff happened, like:
TIME STARTED: Tue Oct 27 2020, 11:14:41 PM
```

Here is my code:

```
import psutil     #psutil - https://github.com/giampaolo/psutil
import time
import sys
import datetime

execute_shell_or_command = sys.executable
found_executable = False

executable_to_find = 'DragonManiaLegends.exe'
iteration = 1
then = time.time()

# Get a list of all running processes
while not found_executable:
    list = psutil.pids()

    # Go though list and check each processes executeable name for 'putty.exe'
    for i in range(0, len(list)):
        try:
            p = psutil.Process(list[i])
            if p.cmdline()[0].find(executable_to_find) != -1:
                # DML found. Kill it
                now = time.time()
                print(f"Found {executable_to_find}. Killing execution...")
                p.kill()
                datetime_str_now = datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(now).strftime('%a %b %d %Y, %I:%M:%S %p')
                datetime_str_then = datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(then).strftime('%a %b %d %Y, %I:%M:%S %p')
                print(f"On {datetime_str_then}, you have started your quest to  t e r m i n a t e  {executable_to_find}"
                      f"\nOn {datetime_str_now}, you have completed that quest, and it has been terminated."
                      f"\nIt only took you {round(now - then)} seconds to elimate {executable_to_find}!")
                # found_executable = True  # Comment this out to loop FOREVER
                # break
        except:
            pass

    if 'python.exe' in execute_shell_or_command:
        now = time.time()
        datetime_str_now = datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(now).strftime('%a %b %d %Y, %I:%M:%S %p')
        datetime_str_then = datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(then).strftime('%a %b %d %Y, %I:%M:%S %p')
        sys.stdout.write(f"\rIt has been {iteration} minute(s) since the past iteration. Since then, some pretty amazing stuff happened, like:\nTIME STARTED: {datetime_str_then}.\nTIME: {datetime_str_now}")
        sys.stdout.flush()
        #  print(f"\rIt has been {iteration} minute(s) since the past iteration. Since then, some pretty amazing stuff happened, like: TIME STARTED: {datetime_str_then}. TIME: {datetime_str_now}", end="", flush=True)
        iteration += 1
    
    time.sleep(60)
```

P.S. I am using Window's command prompt to run the code

Comment: You can go back to the beginning of the current line with`\r`, but you can't jump up a line. To do this, you could use ANSI escape codes, for example.

Answer (score -1):

Try with two `\n`, because one will just insert a line break and another will show a blank line:

```
sys.stdout.write(f"\rIt has been {iteration} minute(s) since the past iteration. Since then, some pretty amazing stuff happened, like:\n\nTIME STARTED: {datetime_str_then}.\n\nTIME: {datetime_str_now}")
```

Comment: What I want is to overwrite the entire string, and that only overwrites the last line